# OpenGL format texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, avfoundation

I am currently trying to display a video on screen using `OpenGL ES 2` on iOS.

I will sum up a bit what I am doing to playback and display the video on screen :

First I have a .mov file recorded using a `GPUImageMovieWriter` object. When the recording is completed I am going to playback the video using `AVPlayer`. Therefore I set a `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` to be able to retrieve frame from the video :

```
NSDictionary *test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber  numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey: (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
        self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:test];
```

I then use the `copyPixelBufferForItemTime` function from the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` and receive the `CVImageBufferRef` corresponding to the frame of the initial video at a specific time.

Finally, here is the function I created to create an `OpenGL` texture from the buffer :

```
- (void)setupTextureFromBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer {

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

  int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
  int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);

  CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_videoTexture);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer));

  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
}
```

By doing this (and also using some non related algorithms to do some augmented reality things) I got a very strange result as if the video has been put in slices(I can't show you because I don't have enough reputation to do so).

It looks like the data are not well interpreted by `OpenGL` (wrong format ? type ?)

I checked whether it could be a corrupted buffer error by using this function :

```
- (void)saveImage:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixBuffer];

    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixBuffer))];

    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

}
```

-> The saved image appeared properly in the photo album.

It may come from the `.mov` file but what can I do to check if there's something wrong with this file ?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm really stuck on this problem for hours/days !

Comment: The best bet would be your pixel buffer does not consist of RGBA data as expected by the texture. Try getting a format from the buffer or at least check the number of bytes per row in the buffer and see if it checks out (4*width). Since it comes from video it might be just RGB data resulting in your image being sliced. Another problem resulting into sliced image can be the buffer data have flipped axis' so width and height are flipped, in this case all you need to do is flip width and height arguments when sending the data to texture.

Comment: Hello eesdee, I checked the number of bytes per row, you were right I got 1440 by calculating 4*bufferWidth and 1472 from the function CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer). It does mean the RGBA format I used is not the correct format of the video right ? I can check the pixel format by using CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType but I'll get a number I don't know what to do with ..

Comment: I made a mistake, I meant : your were right Matic Oblak, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Try something like this to display it: char cString[5];
            cString[4] = 0;
            memcpy(cString, CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(), 4);
            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString];

Comment: Can you tell me the dimensions (width and height) of the buffer.

Comment: i got the same problem, have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange.

Then transfer them to separate chroma and luma OpenGLES textures. Example at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Listings/AVBasicVideoOutput_APLEAGLView_m.html

I tried using several RGB based options but could not make it work.